# Chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0 after committing chaincode to channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

My network is composed of 3 ordering nodes which are in the same orderer organization and 2 peer nodes which are in 2 peer organizations and listening on the port **localhost:20000** and **localhost:20001** respectively. I used the following command to commit my chaincode to the channel named channel1:

```
./peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o localhost:10104 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride localhost --channelID channel1 --name basic --version 1.0 --sequence 1 --tls --cafile ../../../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tls-ca-cert.pem --peerAddresses localhost:20000 --tlsRootCertFiles ../../../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses localhost:20001 --tlsRootCertFiles ../../../organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.example.com/tls/ca.crt
2021-04-16 15:55:30.383 CST [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 001 txid [988fe1654f482a670f90aac12608895a94f64e6beac3e376a54c931b602b27eb] committed with status (VALID) at localhost:20000
2021-04-16 15:55:30.385 CST [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 002 txid [988fe1654f482a670f90aac12608895a94f64e6beac3e376a54c931b602b27eb] committed with status (VALID) at localhost:20001
```

But the peer log showed that it failed to launch the chaincode

```
2021-04-16 15:55:38.224 CST [lifecycle] Work -> WARN 05a could not launch chaincode 'basic_1.0:6116f8e8a64858d76c177dda4143f235820e3f029a81ac39924b60269b6f931c': chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0
```

And the 2 chaincode container logs showed it failed to connect with the corresponding chaincodeListening Addresss 127.0.0.1:20100 and 127.0.0.1:20101.

In **[core.yaml]**, chaincodeListening Address is configured as follows:

```
    # The endpoint this peer uses to listen for inbound chaincode connections.
    # If this is commented-out, the listen address is selected to be
    # the peer's address (see below) with port 7052
    chaincodeListenAddress: 0.0.0.0:20100

    # The endpoint the chaincode for this peer uses to connect to the peer.
    # If this is not specified, the chaincodeListenAddress address is selected.
    # And if chaincodeListenAddress is not specified, address is selected from
    # peer address (see below). If specified peer address is invalid then it
    # will fallback to the auto detected IP (local IP) regardless of the peer
    # addressAutoDetect value.
    chaincodeAddress: localhost:20100
```

```
    # The endpoint this peer uses to listen for inbound chaincode connections.
    # If this is commented-out, the listen address is selected to be
    # the peer's address (see below) with port 7052
    chaincodeListenAddress: 0.0.0.0:20101

    # The endpoint the chaincode for this peer uses to connect to the peer.
    # If this is not specified, the chaincodeListenAddress address is selected.
    # And if chaincodeListenAddress is not specified, address is selected from
    # peer address (see below). If specified peer address is invalid then it
    # will fallback to the auto detected IP (local IP) regardless of the peer
    # addressAutoDetect value.
    chaincodeAddress: localhost:20101
```

```
$ netstat -vanp tcp | grep 20100
tcp46      0      0  *.20100                *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072  33202      0 0x0100 0x00000026
$ netstat -vanp tcp | grep 20101
tcp46      0      0  *.20101                *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072  33495      0 0x0100 0x00000026
```

The peer2 chaincode container logs are as following:

```
Thread[grpc-default-executor-1,5,main] 07:55:37:757 SEVERE  org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeSupportClient$1 onError                Last txid=null An error occurred on the chaincode stream. Shutting down the chaincode stream.UNAVAILABLE: io exception
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:478)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:434)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:763)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:742)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:20101
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:243)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:672)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:649)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:529)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:465)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
.. caused by ..
finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:20101
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:20101
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:243)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:672)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:649)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:529)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:465)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
.. caused by ..
finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:243)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:672)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:649)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:529)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:465)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

How could I solve the problem?:/

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by running peer outside Docker and chaincode container inside Docker. So [localhost] is the local IP address of the Docker virtual machine instead of the local IP address of my laptop.
The most direct solution is running both of them in Docker.